# jQuery Ajax return html AND json data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm not sure if there is any way to do this or not, but this would solve so many of my problems if there is a simple solution to this.

What I need/want to be able to do is return HTML and JSON in my success of ajax request. The reason being, I want to request a file and return all of that page, but I also want to be able to return a specified set of information from the page in json, so I can use it for other things.

This is what I'm doing now:

```
     $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "inc/"+page+".php",
    data: "id="+encodeURIComponent(pageID),
    success: function(html){

        $("body > .container").html(html);

      }
      });
```

This is what I'd like to be able to do:

```
     $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "inc/"+page+".php",
    data: "id="+encodeURIComponent(pageID),
    success: function(html){
        $("body > .container").html(html);
            $("title").html(json.PageTitle)
      }
      });
```

on the page that is being returned, I would specify what I want the title to be. (For instance, if it's a profile, I would return the user's name)

Comment: What stops you having the JSON a HTML string inside?

Comment: Well what do you mean? Do you mean having the JSON on the HTML page itself? If so, then that's how I have done it in the past, but I don't really like to do it like that. To me, it seems like it could be problematic at a point. If there is a better way of doing this, it would help me out a bunch, because I have this issue frequently.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Trying to mix the retun value to contain presentation and data seems like a potential for confusion.  Why not split it into two calls and fetch the data on success of the other?

Something like:

```
 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "inc/"+view_page+".php",
  data: "id="+encodeURIComponent(pageID),
  success: function(html) {
    $("body > .container").html(html);
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "inc/"+data_page+".php",
      data: "id="+encodeURIComponent(pageID),
      success: function(json) {
        $("title").html(json.PageTitle);
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: Thanks, and well yes I know, that's one way of doing this, and also placing the json on my returned page is another way, and that's actually how I have done it in the past, but I feel like that's a messy and maybe not so good way of doing this, maybe the only way though. I'm trying to get everything to work as good together as I can. I've just been curious whether or not this was at all possible, because I run into this issue quite a lot

Comment: It's an interesting question...  I've always tried to preserve the separation of data & display, even at the possible expense of multiple requests.  It will be interesting to see what others come up with.

Comment: I mean this "issue" is probably not something very many people even encounter, so there may not even be another way of doing this, however with my website that I am creating I have a unique setup for everything, as far as handling data and such. To others this may not seem like a problem at all, but to me it would make absolute sense for there to be a way of doing this.

Answer (score 12):

### HTML and data wrapped in JSON

You can do it by returning a 2 element JSON array.
The first element contains HTML and the second element contains another JSON array with the data inside.  You just need to unwrap it carefully without breaking anything.

**Serverside**

```
$html = '<div>This is Html</div>';
$data = json_encode(array('page_title'=>'My Page'));
$response = array('html'=>$html, 'data'=>$data);
echo json_encode($response);
```

**Clientside**

```
//Ajax success function...

success: function(serverResponse){
    $("body > .container").html(serverResponse.html);
    var data = JSON.parse(serverResponse.data);
    $("title").html(data.page_title)
  }
```

---

*Note 1:* I think this is what @hakre meant in his comment on your question.

*Note 2:* This method works, but I would agree with @jheddings that its probably a good idea to avoid mixing presentation and data. Coding karma will come back to bite.

Comment: Just an edit for future readers.
The **Clientside** code last line:
`$("title").html(data.PageTitle)`
should be:
`$("title").html(data.page_title)`

Comment: Tx @FLOQDesign. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You also have the option of including the data in html5 data attributes

For instance, if you're returning a list of Animals

```
<ul id="ZeAnimals" data-total-animals="500" data-page="2">
    <li>Cat</li>
   <li>Dog</li>
   ...
</ul>
```

You can then collect the data you require using

```
$('#ZeAnimals').data('total-animals')
```

Sometimes separating your request into two different ajax calls makes sense also.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a library that does that automatically, like http://phery-php-ajax.net. Using

```php
Phery::instance()->set(array(
  'load' => function(){
    /* mount your $html and $json_data */
    return 
      PheryResponse::factory()
      ->json($json_data)
      ->this() // points to the container
      ->html($html); 
  }
))->process();
```

```js
$(function(){
  var $container = $('body > .container');
  $container.phery('make', 'load'); // or $container.phery().make('load')
  $container.bind('phery:json', function(event, data){
    // deal with data from PHP here
  });
  $container.phery('remote');
});
```

You may, as well, use `phery.views` to automatically load a portion of the site automatically, without having to worry about client-side specific code. You would have to put a unique ID on the container, `container` in this example:

```js
$(function(){
  phery.view({
    '#container': {}
  });
});
```

```php
Phery::instance()->views(array(
  '#container' => function($data, $params){
    /* do the load part in here */
    return 
      PheryResponse::factory()
        ->render_view($html)
        ->jquery('.title')->text($title);
  }
))->process();
```