# extracting array data from (data) in an AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This does not answer the question - [jQuery Ajax return html AND json data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13323393/jquery-ajax-return-html-and-json-data)

I can not use the wrap method because I do not have a single html string. I am not using **Phery**, I have tried the first option here and the second nested call runs before the first so that data is undefined- [jquery Use two done callbacks in same function, one with datatype json one without](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65984992/jquery-use-two-done-callbacks-in-same-function-one-with-datatype-json-one-witho?noredirect=1#comment116665821_65984992)  and we are not using html5 only for this. Therefore the referenced answer does not address the question.

In my `.done` function I have (data) returning. This data is a mixture of php `echo`'s and a single `JSON_encode` array. Sample data:

```
.....
//other divs and data above this point
<div id="test">text</div>
{"ids":["1","5","2","6"]}0
```

**AJAX**

```
.done(function(data) {
console.log(data);
func2(json_string)
})
```

I want to be able to extract and separately work with the array {"ids":["1","5","2","6"]}0. I am trying to pass it along to another function, but only that portion of the data

Comment: Can you not change the PHP script to respond with something more usable?

Comment: What would be more usable? I just cut off the other divs coming back before showing the array I was looking for help with

Comment: For example, use the `Accept` request header to decide whether to respond with HTML or JSON (but not both)

Comment: _more useful_ <--- two alternatives. 1. Put the view partial (the HTML bit) in a string and include that in the encoded object with some key that makes sense to you. 2. Redesign so the view partial is returned from one request and the data from a second request.

Comment: I have both returning in the `data` since I dont know any other way to do it? I could unencode the array coming back but either way need to access it independently to pass only that array along without all the divs

Comment: @randyCashburn, the html that is coming back is NOT in an `$html_string .=''` if that matters. I can change how this all comes in, yes. Just not sure how to do so.  The real key is being able to separate out that array from the rest so I can pass only that array position onto another function. I still need the other html data inside of the first function since I append it

Comment: _"This does not answer the question"_... there are four answers on that post and only one of them mentions _wrapping_

Comment: @phil please see above for specific comments on each and every method there and why it does not answer the question

Comment: Perhaps you can use a combination of Javasript indexOf() and substr() methods to detect the opening and closing braces of the JSON string and extract that out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a very simple content-negotiation example using a query string parameter...

In your PHP, break up your HTML and JSON parts like this

```php
<?php
$format = $_GET["format"] ?? "html";
if ($format === "json") {
    header("Content-type: application/json");
    echo json_encode(["ids" => [1, 5, 2, 6]]);
    exit;
}
?>
.....
//other divs and data above this point
<div id="test">text</div>
```

Then in your JavaScript code, fetch the two parts using

```js
$.ajax(my_ajax.ajax_url, {
  dataType: "html",
  // etc
}).done(html => {
  // html content here
})
```

and

```js
$.ajax(`${my_ajax.ajax_url}?format=json`, {
  dataType: "json",
  // etc
}).done(json => {
  // json content here
})
```

Comment: Would this also work if the php cant be broken up because the ids are coming from a foeach loop that is also  used to generate some of the html?

Comment: I don't know what you mean since I cannot see your PHP code. If this hasn't answered your question, why did you accept it?